# Gstreamer Video Sink for Raspberry Pi

Tags: video, gstreamer, raspberry-pi, openmax

I m working on a Raspberry pi board with gstreamer 1.0 inbstalled. I was testing some pipelines on the board. But in Raspberry pi the video sink is not working.
I tried different videosinks such as `ximagesink, xvimagesink, autovideosink etc`

But none of these videosinks are able to play video.

The error I am getting is

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0: Could not initialise Xv output
Additional debug info:
xvimagesink.c(1290): gst_xvimagesink_xcontext_get (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0:
```

Is there any other video sinks that I can use with Raspberry pi so that I can view view videos with gstreamer ?

Is there any video sink specially made for Broadcom 2835 or Does openmax provide any videosink ?

And Does anyone have any idea to resolve this XvOutput issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message implies to me that the Xv libraries are not installed. I'm not sure what type of distro you are running on the Raspberry Pi, but if it's a Debian/Ubuntu-type distro, the package name for Xv appears to be 'libxv1'.

However, you indicated that ximagesink doesn't work. I would expect ximagesink to work, as long as there is an X server running. Is an X server running?

Also, run 'gst-inspect | grep sink' to find all the sinks installed (at least, all the GStreamer elements with 'sink' in the element name).